# How to count each character from the Textarea using react and display total count?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to count each character from textarea and display the character count. I have done the total character count but How do I count each character and display the number of characters?
My code is follows :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Home() {
  const [characterCount, setCharacterCount] = useState(0);

  const myFunction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={myFunction}>
        <h3>Please enter text</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setCharacterCount(e.target.value.length)}
          placeholder="start typing"
        ></textarea>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
        <p>Total number of character :{characterCount}</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

output:
user input

```
    abbbsewrrrrree
Total number of characters: 14
```

Expected:
Example:
if user input:

`abbbsewrrrrree`

```
a=1
b=3
s=1
e=3
w=1
r=5
```

Comment: Does this help? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript?rq=1).

Comment: it is different. I want to know how we count each character from textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should make the input(textarea) controlled, as you would like to process the value (to count each character).
[React Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

```js
function Home() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const myFunction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={myFunction}>
        <h3>Please enter text</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="start typing"
        ></textarea>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
        <p>Total number of character :{text.length}</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And for counting each character you could use `useMemo` and watch state `text` changes, like this:

```js
function Home() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const myFunction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
  };

  const eachCharResult = useMemo(() => {
    let result = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (result[text[i]]) result[text[i]]++;
      else result[text[i]] = 1;
    }
    return result;
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={myFunction}>
        <h3>Please enter text</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="start typing"
        ></textarea>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
        <p>Total number of character :{text.length}</p>
      </form>
      {Object.keys(eachCharResult).map((el, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{`${el}: ${eachCharResult[el]}`}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ignoring space, you can solve like this:

```js
const removeSpace = (text) => text.replace(/\s/g, '');

function Home() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const myFunction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
  };

  const eachCharResult = useMemo(() => {
    let result = {};
    let textWithoutSpace = removeSpace(text);
    for (let i = 0; i < textWithoutSpace.length; i++) {
      if (result[textWithoutSpace[i]]) result[textWithoutSpace[i]]++;
      else result[textWithoutSpace[i]] = 1;
    }
    return result;
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={myFunction}>
        <h3>Please enter text</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="start typing"
        ></textarea>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
        <p>Total number of character :{removeSpace(text).length}</p>
      </form>
      {Object.keys(eachCharResult).map((el, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{`${el}: ${eachCharResult[el]}`}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can we select or highlight most repeated words like any four or five most frequent character?

Comment: yeah sure, you can achieve that by manipulating this `eachCharResult`

Comment: do we check each character in function ? can you update that in the code ?

Comment: I was wondering same like how can we highlight the most repeated character like the 5 most frequent characters in the text.

Comment: for that I think you should make another thread question, share the link and I'll help you there :)

Comment: Here is the link for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805242/how-to-highlight-most-frequent-character-in-the-text-from-texarea-using-reactjs

Comment: @Andara Why does numbers shows first if it is in the middle of text ? eg: if user input `aaabb111cc` it show `1:3,a:3,b:2,c:2` isn't it suppose to show `a:3,b:2,1:3,c:2`  ? if it is counting order wise character.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (I didn't run it)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// new
const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
const counts = {}
alphabet.split('').forEach(letter => counts[letter] = 0)

function Home() {
  const [characterCount, setCharacterCount] = useState(0);

  // new 
  const [letterCount, setLetterCount] = useState(counts)

  // new 
  const onTextChange = e => {
      setCharacterCount(e.target.value.length)

      // update count for letter
      const l = e.target.value[e.target.value.length -1]
      letterCount[l] += 1
      setLetterCount(letterCount)
  }

  const myFunction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={myFunction}>
        <h3>Please enter text</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => onTextChange(e)}  // <-- new
          placeholder="start typing"
        ></textarea>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
        <p>Total number of character :{characterCount}</p>
        {
            // new
            Object.keys(letterCount).map(li => {
                 return <p key={`key-${li}`>{li}: {letterCount[li]}</p>
            })

      }

      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Okay, I updated the key, the other problem should be easy to figure out. Rewrite ```onTextChange``` to subtract instead of add depending on if they are adding or removing. You already have the length if that helps.

Comment: It add total count if i delete the same character like if user enter `aa` and remove `aa` then it displays total count of `a=4` also it shows `: NaN
undefined : NaN` at the end of list.

Answer (score 0):

Check that solution, got the character count function [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297978/5041988)

```js
function Char_Count(str1) {
  let chars = {};
  str1.replace(/\S/g, function (l) {
    chars[l] = isNaN(chars[l]) ? 1 : chars[l] + 1;
  });
  return chars;
}

function Home() {
  const [characterCount, setCharacterCount] = useState({});

  const onTextAreaChange = (e) => {
    setCharacterCount(Char_Count(e.target.value));
  };

  const myFunction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={myFunction}>
        <h3>Please enter text</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={onTextAreaChange}
          placeholder="start typing"
        ></textarea>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
        <p>All character counts:</p>
        {Object.keys(characterCount).map((item, i) => (
          <p key={i}>
            {item}: {characterCount[item]}
          </p>
        ))}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If we want to sort the `characterCount` object based on the most repeated character, we can update the `onTextAreaChange` to this:

```js
  const onTextAreaChange = (e) => {
    const countObj = Char_Count(e.target.value);
    const sortableCountObj = Object.entries(countObj)
      .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)
      .reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({ ...r, [k]: v }), {});

    setCharacterCount(sortableCountObj);
  };
```

[image: Edit react-count-each-character]

Comment: I have one question how do you select or highlight most repeated words like any four or five most frequent character?

Comment: @Sprug We can sort the `characterCount` object I think. Got the hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/5041988). 
I have updated the answer and CodeSandbox, please check.

Comment: Why does numbers shows first if it is in the middle of text ? eg: if user input `aaabb111cc` it show `1:3,a:3,b:2,c:2` isn't it suppose to show `a:3,b:2,1:3,c:2` ? if it is counting order wise character

Comment: It is counting/sorting based on the most frequent characters, not order wise. 
However, it seems not to sort the numbers properly. The reason is after sorting, we are converting the sorted array to an object. I found Javascript always puts number keys at first!