# How to highlight most frequent character in the text from texarea using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can we highlight the most repeated character like the 5 most frequent characters in the text.
Here is the code that is used to count each character from the textarea.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";

const removeSpace = (text) => text.replace(/\s/g, "");

function Home() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const eachCharResult = useMemo(() => {
    let result = {};
    let textWithoutSpace = removeSpace(text);
    for (let i = 0; i < textWithoutSpace.length; i++) {
      if (result[textWithoutSpace[i]]) result[textWithoutSpace[i]]++;
      else result[textWithoutSpace[i]] = 1;
    }
    return result;
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <h3>Please enter text</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="start typing"
        ></textarea>
        <p>Total number of character :{removeSpace(text).length}</p>
      </form>
      {Object.keys(eachCharResult).map((el, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{`${el}: ${eachCharResult[el]}`}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

I want to highlight the text that are repeated most frequently in the text like in image `t` is repeated for `5` times followed by  `s e o i`. Displaying them as `most repeated character`
and show total count of `t s e o i`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell you are aiming for, you want to list the 5 most common characters and their counts. You can sort an array of entries, keep the top 5 results, and then map them to JSX.

```
Object.entries(eachCharResult)
  .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a) // <-- sort by the values (i.e. letter counts)
  .slice(0, 5)                   // <-- keep first 5 entries
  .map(([key, value], i) => (
    <p key={key}>
      {key}: {value}
    </p>
  ))
```

[image]

[image: Edit how-to-highlight-most-frequent-character-in-the-text-from-texarea-using-reactjs]