# Manipulation array data in js ( Logic Test )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need help how to solve this logic in my JS code, for input - output flow same as I draw on the paper

Thanks in advance.

[image: an example of the logic flow that I drew]

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: my expected output is from TOP - Break 5 will appear in the input component :)

Comment: i fail to understand your expected output. what you have on that paper is code work flow. an output is like an array, an object, string or number.

Comment: are the duplicates consecutive always as given?

Comment: do you want your code to output something like this `{"123": 5, "66": 1, "55": 1, "32": 2}`?

Comment: useful docs you should read: [split string method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [count number of occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480916/count-number-of-occurrences-for-each-char-in-a-string)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
const string = "123*123*123*123*123*66*55*32*32"

const arr = string.split("*")

const output = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr] = (prev[curr]?? 0) + 1
  return prev 
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

[Using Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)