# Number of occurrence of each element in string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to find out number of occurrences of each element in string. for example string str="aabacdbccdd". a=3, b=2, c=3, d=3.

I am getting error at below loop.
Constraints and l are strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < constraints.size(); i++)
{
    size_t mycount = std::count(l.begin(), l.end(), constraints[i]);                    
}
```

Error is:
No operator found which takes a left-hand of operand of type 'char'

Could you please help what is the error over here.

Thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213422/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-letter-in-string).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Which of these lines is the error message referring to?

Comment: I think the error is somewhere else, put more code before and after this bloc so we can see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

I assume `constraints` is a container of `string`.

`l.begin()` and `l.end()` are `char` iterators. 
You can not compare a `char` with a `string`.

change:

```
constraints[i]
```

to

```
constraints[i][0]
```

Or try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const std::string alphabet("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz");
    std::string l("aabacdbccdd");

    for (const char& c : alphabet) {
        size_t mycount = std::count(l.begin(), l.end(), c);
        std::cout << c << " = " << mycount << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a = 3
b = 2
c = 3
d = 3
e = 0
...
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. constraints[i][0] works here. But roight now I am looking for a fatstest method to calculate numbers of occuranence of each element in a string as my string contsians arnd 2 millions elements.

Comment: @user3022426 Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and up-voting if it helped.